# Fuzzy, blown out sound on speakers only in Chrome

Tags: sound, google-chrome, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm getting a fuzzy sound when playing audio on Google Chrome, almost like the speakers are about to blow out. This only happens when playing from the built-in speakers; headphone input is fine. Running Ubuntu 18.04 on an Asus ZenBook

Solutions I've tried:

- Removing and reinstalling `alsa-base`, `pulseaudio` and `indicator-sound`
- Set `load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0`
- Adjusted levels using PaVu and `alsa-mixer`

Not a huge dealbreaker but I'm more just curious as to what could possibly be causing this...

Comment: Does this occur with other browsers, such as Firefox, or no-browser music apps such as Clementine?

Comment: This used to only be occurring in Chrome, however after trying these options I somehow made is a system-wide issue

Comment: Rebooting solves the issue, but only for Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem last night. It had something to do with audio power saving or something. This worked for me. Add the following to the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Ah unfortunately it didn't work, I was curious if it was something power related and trying to investigate that though. Thanks!